# Show HTML symbol codes as code, not as symbol

Tags: html, css

I am trying to show html symbol codes on a web site, in the code format, not the actual symbol. I want `&lt;` not `<`. I have looked at the HTML here, and it seems the code tool wraps a line of code in `<code></code>` with an outer wrapper of `<pre></pre>`. All of which means this looks right here on stack overflow.

```
<With>&lt;Path&gt;\\Prlx1</With>
```

But when I use Pre and Code the same way on my own site, the codes are processed and I get `<With><Path>\\Prlx1</With>`. Obviously something is wrong in my definition of Pre or Code, but I am not sure what I am looking for in the CSS.

```css
.px_code {
  line-height: 1em;
  font-size: .7em;
  font-family: monospace;
  font-weight: normal;
  background-color: #fff;
  margin-bottom: 0!important;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  display: inline;
}

.px_ind3 {
  margin-left: 4.5em;
}

.px_cc_n {
  /* Node */
  color: #0000CC;
  display: inline;
}

.px_cc_t {
  /* Text */
  color: #000000;
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<code class="px_code px_ind3 px_cc_n">&lt;With&gt;<span class="px_cc_t">&lt;Path&gt;C:\Parallax</span>&lt;/With&gt;</code>
```

FWIW, I am providing documentation on a web site, for a PowerShell utility that stores it's data in XML, and in this case the tool modifies an XML text file, so the shown XML includes the symbols so when the utility reads the XML it ends up with the correct replace string, which is `<Path>\\Prlx1`. The styling is there to color code the example so it looks like it looks in NotePad++.

Comment: try to use <xmp>

Comment: @セアンデエ do you mean just wrap the symbol code in <xmp>, or replace my use of <code> with <xmp> throughout?

Comment: should it be like this?

link: https://jsfiddle.net/p01nwe32/

Comment: If anyone has a comment on the overall approach, especially if that comment starts with "THAT'S STUPID! Do it it this way..." I am all ears. More than a little inexperienced here. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`&lt;` in HTML *means* "<". If you want to display "&lt;", you need to code it as `&amp;lt;`. You need to HTML-encode HTML special characters. `&` is a special character in HTML, so you need to encode it to `&amp;` for it to lose its special meaning.

Comment: Aha, two levels of symbol encoding! So obvious in hindsight.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use `<xmp>`, but it escapes tags too

```
<xmp>&lt;With&gt;</xmp>
<code class="px_code px_ind3 px_cc_n">&lt;With&gt;<span class="px_cc_t">&lt;Path&gt;C:\Parallax</span>&lt;/With&gt;</code>
<xmp>&lt;With&gt;<span class="px_cc_t">&lt;Path&gt;C:\Parallax</span>&lt;/With&gt;</xmp>
```